# Blender 3.2 / Chest jiggle with cloth physics / Render problem

Tags: rendering, physics, cloth-simulation

Animation works nicely when i bake cloth physics. When I rendering the animation as a image, it doesn't take the cloth physics. Could you help?

Comment: If render and preview disagree, it is likely to be from different render/preview settings for modifiers (visibility buttons, or subdivision iterations), or from objects that hidden in viewports but not in render.

Comment: like your expression. I closed it so that the object I created for the body would not be visible. It worked with the wire view. Thanks senior